# C# : how to obtain solution configuration options?

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Solution configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyLON.png)
I now do is a performance test, only used in the debugging phase.Need to manually adjust the #define when deployed。

Whether can debug or release through solution configuration, to determine the #define code execution。

Through what way can, do not need to manually adjust the #define, to control code execution。

If I didn't describe clearly, please leave a message to tell me

Comment: "Need to manually adjust the #define when deployed" - You can't. `#define` statements are processed by the compiler. You can create multiple build configurations with different code in the `#define` blocks and deploy each configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> "Need to manually adjust the #define when deployed"

You cannot do this. `#define` statements are processed by the compiler.

There are a number of possible solutions to your problem depending on what it actually is.

You can create multiple build configurations with different code in the `#define` blocks and deploy each configuration to test.

or

You can use feature switches, which is just a way to turn on and off bits of code depending on, for example, settings in a configuration file.